# How can I add a class to an element when the scroll exceeds some value?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a class to an element when the scroll pixel exceeds 2px, but it isn't working. Please what is it not working?

```
 className={`arrowup ${window.pageYOffset >= 2 ? "showscroll":null}`}
```

Comment: use an empty string as fallback

Comment: You haven't provided any means for this to update the DOM after initial rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onScroll event to your div that you want to make scrollable and attach a reference to it using useRef hook. Everytime your div scrolls, fire a function handleScroll and set your scroll state accordingly. You will need to set some height and give overflow-y:scroll to your scrollable div to actually see it. This should help you out.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);
  const divRef = React.useRef();

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    const scrolledFromTop = divRef.current.scrollTop;
    console.log(scrolledFromTop);
    setScroll(scrolledFromTop > 2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={scroll ? "showscroll" : ""}>toggle class here</div>
      <div className="area" onScroll={handleScroll} ref={divRef}>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```